# Unable to sign into Firebase account

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

It seems that I am unable to sign into an account that's on Firebase.

I honestly don't know what to try. I'm at a loss for what to do, as I am very new to Firebase.

Here is the code for signing in:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Log in</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form onsubmit="signin()">
      <input id="email" type="email" name="email">
      <input id="password" type="password" name="password">
      <input type="submit" Value="Log in">
    </form>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "api key",
    authDomain: "domain",
    databaseURL: "databaseurl",
    projectId: "id",
    storageBucket: "bucket",
    messagingSenderId: "senderid"
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  function signin() {
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      // ...
    });
  }
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then here is the code for the account page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="useremail"></h1>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
var config = {
  apiKey: "api key",
  authDomain: "domain",
  databaseURL: "databaseurl",
  projectId: "id",
  storageBucket: "bucket",
  messagingSenderId: "senderid"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    document.getElementById("useremail").innerHTML = "Logged in";
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
    document.getElementById("useremail").innerHTML = "Not logged in";
  }
});
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you are signed into an account, the account page should display "Signed in" however it says that it isn't, even though I believe I have signed into an account using the sign in page.

Url of website: https://calculatingclutteredgreenware--mrsprinkletoes.repl.co/

Comment: How do you get from the sign-in page to the account page?

Comment: You just navigate there yourself

Comment: OK. In that case: 1) add the `onAuthStateChanged` to your sign-in page, 2) check if it fires with the user being logged in.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I changed the login page to this: https://pastebin.com/FhC90WQr

However, it still doesn't change to "Logged in", it just says "Not logged in" after I attempt to sign in.

Comment: That means the problem at least is not related to the second page. Please update your question to contain the single page that shows sign-in failing. You're essentially reducing the scope of the problem, which makes it more likely someone can help. Did you check if your `catch` gets called, and if so what `error` contains?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'll add the url to the page, where you can try registering an account then logging into it. (I know that account creation works, I can see each one being created and added to the list of users on the Firebase Console)

I added a console.log to the error function thing, and it seems to not be called.

Comment: That all sounds good. Please update your question to show the log, and its output, and to reduce the question to only have a single page (since it seems reproducible with that). I highly recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as that's what I'm trying to get to here, as I honestly don't yet see what's going wrong from the information you've provided.